# Android NoClass DefFoundError how to solve it?

Tags: android

I am uploading video to youtube but class defFounderror is occured?....

My class is ::

```
import com.google.gdata.data.youtube.VideoEntry;
import com.google.gdata.data.youtube.YouTubeMediaGroup;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        VideoEntry newEntry = new VideoEntry();
    }
}
```

Logcat ::

```
 10-25 12:18:30.214: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(343): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.gdata.data.youtube.VideoEntry
    10-25 12:18:30.214: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(343):     at com.logistics.main.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:10)
    10-25 12:18:30.214: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(343):     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
    10-25 12:18:30.214: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(343):     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1429)
    10-25 12:18:30.214: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(343):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
    10-25 12:18:30.214: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(343):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2577)
    10-25 12:18:30.214: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(343):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
    10-25 12:18:30.214: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(343):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
    10-25 12:18:30.214: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(343):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
```

Comment: its not activity so why add it ? how to add it?

Comment: Are you using this library http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/ ?

Comment: @aromero..i want to upload video to youtube you have any idea or any source code.and in your link there  are three version for api...

Answer (score 0):

Apparently class was on compile classpath ( ptherwise it would not compile at all) but was not included into APK.  Which build environment / tools are you using?

Comment: plz explain me how  environment or tools use?

Comment: what are you using to build your APK? which tools?

Comment: i am directly usb debugging with my device.....is create prblm due to unsign apk?